# Simplest way to erase and replace content of multiples text files

Tags: file-management, text-editing

I'm trying to do quite a simple thing. I have 40 text files in which in need to delete everything and replace with the content of a template text-file.

What is the easiest/fastest way?

NB: I don't want to search and replace, but to delete everything and then copy inside. That would be like opening the file, ctrl + A >> del >> ctrl + v for each file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unix-like

On a Unix-like command-line (on Linux, OSX, etc.) you can use `cat` to print the contents of a file to STDOUT, and `>` to redirect STDOUT to a file, over-writing its contents.

```
cat template.txt > file.txt
```

The easiest way is to put `template.txt` in a separate directory, then you can use a for loop to affect every *.txt in  the working directory:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do cat /path/to/template.txt > "$f"; done
```

On systems with bash 4+ (any modern *nix is likely to have this; check with `bash --version`), you can use extended globbing, so you can have `template.txt` in the same directory as the files you wish to over-write:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in ./!(*template).txt; do cat template.txt > "$f"; done
```

If you have text files in many subdirectories (WARNING: THIS WILL OVER-WRITE **ALL** `*.txt` FILES IN THE WORKING DIRECTORY AND ALL ITS SUB-DIRECTORIES, AND ALL THEIR SUB-DIRECTORIES...), you can use globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.txt; do cat /path/to/template.txt > "$f"; done

##  OR:
shopt -s globstar extglob
for f in ./**/!(*template).txt; do cat template.txt > "$f"; done
```

## Windows

This works similarly, though the syntax is different. Instead of `cat`, use `type`:

```
type template.txt > file.txt
```

To work on every `.txt` in a directory:

```
FOR %F IN (*.txt) DO type C:\path\to\template.txt > %F
```

For recursiveness, use `/R`:

```
FOR /R %F IN (*.txt) DO type C:\path\to\template.txt > %F
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `cat` or `type` instead of `cp` or `copy`?

Comment: @terdon only that for some reason this solution is what came into my head first.

Comment: It works (i'm on a windows platform, no linux at work) but it erase the content of the template, is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you want could be done by an automated search and replace(like what powergrep does but free), but it's easier to just take the template and copy it as each new file. This can be done from the command line.

Create a file with a list of all the filenames you want to put that template in.

So listoffiles.txt has contents:

> file1.txt
>   file2.txt
>   file3.txt

Then open a cmd prompt and do:

> C:\fdf>for /f %f in (listoffiles.txt) do @echo copy template.txt %f
>
> copy template.txt file1.txt
>   copy template.txt file2.txt
>   copy template.txt file3.txt
>
> C:\fdf>

Just change the @echo copy template.txt line, to read  copy template.txt. i.e. remove the @echo or just the echo.

You need listoffiles.txt in c:\fdf  and template.txt in there too. And it will create file1.txt file2.txt etc.